# Building Firewall for Deployed System

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have an approach I would like feedback on for building a firewall for a system that is already deployed (i.e., multiple servers running in the field with no firewall whatsoever). All of the servers in question are running Linux (RHEL 6 to be exact).

My thought process is to run netstat on each of the servers and look for listening ports (netstat -lnp | grep $pid for each pid I know I care about), and then just add each port to the iptables configuration (using system-config-firewall-tui). The /etc/sysconfig/iptables file would then be saved and controlled for the next deployed system.

I’m sure there are holes in my plan, but does anyone have any suggestions for making this work? Do I need to include any ports other than the listening ports on each server? Is netstat sufficient for finding these ports or do I need to use another tool (e.g., wireshark)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to know the expected and desired connectivity of your running applications which will quite possibly  be different from how they are currently configured. So getting a list of open ports is a good start but only half of the equation.

Simply activating a firewall with rules to allow all incoming traffic to every port that is  currently open will not break anything but does not improve your security at all either ...

For instance on a LAMP stack the MYSQL server may well be configured to accept network connections on port 3307 even though all the web applications that use that database server will be running on the server itself.
 Then there should be no reason to ever allow incoming remote network connections on port 3307 in your firewall.